# How to bind variables in Clojure macros?

Tags: variables, binding, clojure, macros, cursive

I'm trying to write a macro that takes a vector of bindings and a function that can access these bindings. In the simplest form:

```
(defmacro f-with-binds [binds f]
  `(let [~@binds]
     ~f))
```

even though the above works:

```
(f-with-binds [n 123 m 456] (println n m)) ;; => 123 456
```

I am not happy with this because Cursive highlights `n` and `m` as undeclared variables which does not happen for macros like `for` and `let` . How can I improve my implementation?

ps.: the real macro returns a transducer - bindings are the transducer's state and function is the transducer's step function

Comment: Maybe `let` and `for` are handled as special cases in Cursive? It's hard to say since Cursive is closed source.

Comment: by the way, you don't need to do `[~@binds]`. You can use `(let ~binds ~f)`.

Comment: @leetwinski lol, you're right, thanks

Comment: This is a known issue in Cursive that is currently being worked on (see, for example https://github.com/cursive-ide/cursive/issues/147). For now the only remedy seems to be in the beta version `1.3.0-eap1`, where you can instruct Cursive to resolve bindings in your macro as if it was a `let`: https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/macros.html Another solution would be to disable highlighting of unresolved symbols entirely (Settings → Languages & Frameworks → Clojure → Highlight Unresolved Symbols).

Comment: @superkonduktr oh! Thank you sir.

Comment: @juan.facorro you were right after all ;)

Comment: `f` need not be a function; it can be any form that the bindings close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taken from @superkonduktr comment:

This is a known issue in Cursive that is currently being [worked on](http://github.com/cursive-ide/cursive/issues/147). For now the only remedy seems to be in the beta version 1.3.0-eap1, where you can instruct Cursive to resolve bindings in your macro [as if it was a let](http://cursive-ide.com/userguide/macros.html). Another solution would be to disable highlighting of unresolved symbols entirely (Settings → Languages & Frameworks → Clojure → Highlight Unresolved Symbols).